# iOS - Unable to access NSMutableArray in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, exc-bad-access

I am unable to access my NSMutableArray in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` although i am able to access it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Here is my code :-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"drinks" ofType:@"plist"];
    self.drinkArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.drinkArray);
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NSLog(@"I am inside cellForRowAtIndexPath");
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    NSDictionary *dict = [self.drinkArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"name"]; 
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    [dict release];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    DrinkDetails *detailViewController = [[DrinkDetails alloc] initWithNibName:@"DrinkDetails" bundle:nil];
    // ...
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    //detailViewController.drink = [self.drinkArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"%@", self.drinkArray);

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];

}
```

Sometime NSLog prints some stupid output and sometime it gives me an error "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

Please take a look and check what is wrong with my code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one (*really two*) issues, but the main one is in your `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
[dict release];
```

Get rid of this line and it should work just fine.

The reason why this fixes your issue is because `-objectAtIndex:` simply returns a **pointer to the requested object in memory**, therefore you do not (and should not) send the `-release` message to that object because the `NSArray` obtained ownership of the object when it was inserted. Sending `-release` to this object reference effectively deallocates the object in memory and now this indice in the `NSArray` is pointing to garbage memory. **BAD BAD BAD**

The other issue is that you have a memory leak here:

```
self.drinkArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

You are sending the `-retain` message to an object reference that you already have ownership of by way of sending `-alloc`. (This of course assumes that your `@property` has the `retain` setter modifier)

To fix this issue, simply send the `-autorelease` message to this instance:

```
self.drinkArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path] autorelease];
```

Comment: What is the second issue in my code? I am new to iPhone SDK so i would appreciate if you tell me whats more i could improve in this code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Don't release an object unless it was created with `alloc` or obtained with a method beginning with `new` or `copy` or explicitly `retain`'ed. (NARC)

In this case:

NSDictionary *dict = [self.drinkArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

was not returned retained so you do not have ownership and should not release it.

By the same token:

```
self.drinkArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

is alloc'ed so it needs to be released or obtained with a convince method that will return an autoreleased object:

```
self.drinkArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a nice answer. Definitely +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't `[dict release]`in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. `objectAtIndex` does not retain it, so it may be sweeped out of your array when you release it.